# Why the transform translate is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using this code to simply move a small element(ball here), but the transform translate is only working once, even when the `setInterval()` function is continuously working?
This is the `html` file --

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="MoveTheBall.css">
    <title>Move the ball</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ball"></div>

    <script src="MoveTheBall.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and `CSS` file--

```
.ball{
    height: 5rem;
    width: 5rem;
    background-color: salmon;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    top: 35vw;
    left: 45vw;
}
```

and the `JavaScript` file--

```
var ball = document.querySelector('.ball');
document.addEventListener('keypress' , function(event) {
    console.log('key', event.key);
    if(event.key === 'w') {
        moveUp();
    }
});

function moveUp() {
    let ballRect;
    let interval = setInterval(function() {
        ballRect = ball.getBoundingClientRect();
        if(ballRect.top > 0) {
            ball.style.transform = 'translateY(-10px)';
        } else {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 300);
}
```

Here I was expecting to move the ball up until it reaches to the top of the screen after pressing `w` key. But the ball is only moving only once.

Comment: The CSS file is missing

Comment: The ball only moves once because `translateY` is always relative to the original position, meaning the "translate calls" are not accumulating. You would have to keep track of the delta (already moved distance).

Comment: @Palladium02 can you provide short code to show the use of delta here

Answer (score 0):

It is because you always **set** the translate to `-10px`. If you want to always add `-10px` to the transform, you would need to store it in a variable:

```js
let translatePixels = 0

function moveUp() {
    let ballRect;
    let interval = setInterval(function() {
        ballRect = ball.getBoundingClientRect();
        if(ballRect.top > 0) {
            translatePixels -= 10
            ball.style.transform = `translateY(${translatePixels}px)`;
        } else {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 300);
}
```